# Laravel 5.5 - Force user to do some action on each page load

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, authorization

In Laravel 5.5 is it possible to prevent already signed-in user from accessing any page other than one I specify?

**Example:** I would like to force user to select his/her Time zone under their profile before letting them access any other menu item. Hiding menu items until Time zone is selected is not an option. I've read about guards, middleware but cannot understand much of it.

Thank you.

Comment: What version of Laravel 5 are you using?

Comment: I think a middleware would be your best choice. There are many tutorials about it like https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-laravel-middleware

Comment: @RossWilson It is 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a middleware here middleware are the best choice to do task like this you can refer the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware) for getting more about middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AfterMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // your whatever logic

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```